# Dynamic loading of menu options seems not to respect order of results from cypher

Tags: cypher, structr

I'm trying to influence the order of navigation menu options by setting  Page.Position to 1 and 2 and providing this cypher

```
start n=node:keywordAllNodes(type='Page') return n order by n.Position ;
```

but it does not seem to make a difference. What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property names are all lowercase, just displayed 'titleized'.

With Neo4j 2.0, you can write the query as

```
MATCH (n:Page) RETURN n ORDER BY n.position
```

Of course, all position properties have to be set in order to make sorting work.